# Alternative to creating multipart .tar.gz files?

Tags: linux, compression, split, gzip, tar

I have a folder with >20GB of images on a linux server, I need to make a backup and download it, so I was thinking about using "split" to create 1GB files. My question is: instead of splitting a .tar.gz and then having to join it again on my computer, is there a way I could create 20 x 1GB valid .tar.gz files, so I can then view/extract them separately?

Edit: I forgot to add that I need to do it without ssh access. I'm using mostly PHP.

Comment: So what you need is a PHP script that lets you transfer (download) all those images from the server?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use rsync?

FYI, rsync is a command-line tool that synchronises directories between two machines across the network. If you have Linux at both ends and ssh access properly configured, it's as simple as `rsync -av server:/path/to/images/ images/` (make sure the trailing slashes are there). It also optimises subsequent synchronisations so that only changes are transmitted. You can even tell it to compress data in transit, but that usually doesn't help with images.

Comment: I don't know what that is, I'm quite new to *nix systems, I will do some research.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) to backup using rsync/hardlinks instead. It not only solves the filesize issue but also gives you high storage and bandwidth efficiency when existing images aren't changed often.

Answer (score 0):

First I would give rsnapshot a miss if you don't have SSH access. (Though I do and love it)

I would assume you're likely backing up jpeg's and they are already compressed. Zipping them up doesn't make them much smaller, plus you don't need exactly 1GB files. It sounds like they can be a bit bigger or smaller.

So you could just write a script which bundles jpegs into a gz(or whatever) until it has put about 1gb worth in and then starts a new archive.

You could do all this in PHP easy enough.